# SQL get records that expire in 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope someone can point out what I'm doing wrong because I have no idea. It's my first time using the DATEADD. I tried putting +7,+8 just in case but nothing. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I only need the records from 7 days, not between those days.

```
SELECT  A.ID
       ,B.EMAIL
       ,A.NUMBER 
       ,A.EXPIRATION

  FROM vw_RECORD AS A
  LEFT JOIN vw_INFO AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
  WHERE NUMBER LIKE 'C%'
  AND A.EXPIRATION = DATEADD(DAY,7,GETDATE())
```

The result without the last AND statement gets me:

```
ID          EMAIL           NUMBER         EXPIRATION
530c    email@gmail.com     C-0001    2017-08-29 00:00:00.000
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, `GETDATE()` (despite its name) has a time component.  So, you need to remove it:

```
A.EXPIRATION = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thank you bro. That did it! I didn't think I needed to convert because in the properties the column says data type in datetime.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that DATEADD can't accept DAY as the first argument, since it uses abbrevations (e.g mm for month), so the code would look like this :

```
SELECT  A.ID
       ,B.EMAIL
       ,A.NUMBER 
       ,A.EXPIRATION

  FROM vw_RECORD AS A
  LEFT JOIN vw_INFO AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
  WHERE NUMBER LIKE 'C%'
  AND A.EXPIRATION = DATEADD(dd,7,GETDATE())
```

Also as getdate adds time to the end and I'm guessing expiration also has time part since you probably just added 7 days to the current date, it'll never be the exact same. You could try converting both without a time part like this :

```
SELECT  A.ID
       ,B.EMAIL
       ,A.NUMBER 
       ,A.EXPIRATION

  FROM vw_RECORD AS A
  LEFT JOIN vw_INFO AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
  WHERE NUMBER LIKE 'C%'
  AND CONVERT(date, A.EXPIRATION) = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(dd,7,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: No need to guess, the documentation shows `day`, `d`, or `dd`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation, I didn't have time to search since I'm at work, was just scrolling around stackoverflow 'cos I needed something and stumbled upon this.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
  SELECT  A.ID
           ,B.EMAIL
           ,A.NUMBER 
           ,A.EXPIRATION
      FROM vw_RECORD AS A
      LEFT JOIN vw_INFO AS B ON A.ID=B.ID
      WHERE NUMBER LIKE 'C%'
      AND DATEDIFF(DAY,A.EXPIRATION,GETDATE())=7
```